# CLRegionStateUnknown Until Map Refresh

Tags: ios, core-location, region

It seems that I'm running into a delegate issue when using regions with CLLocationManager. When I first run the project, I add various regions to the manager and call requestStateForRegion: to determine if I'm currently within any of them.  The manager then calls my didDetermineState: function (rather quickly it seems) but all of the passed CLRegionStates are unknown.

When I go into the Maps app and find my current location, then relaunch my application within a few minutes, the states are found correctly.

I've set about 10 regions where one of which is my hard-coded current location, but my current location still shows as unknown.  Any ideas?

```
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    manager.delegate = self;

    if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    for (CLRegion *monitored in [manager monitoredRegions]) {
        [manager stopMonitoringForRegion:monitored];
    }

    NSArray *events = ...;
    for (Event *event in events) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
        CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:50.0 identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventID]];
        [manager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
```

Comment: you authorize the manager alright? like.. you have the plist key and call requestAuth and so on? -- can you provide us the code where you set it up?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Posted code, but everything looks fine to me.